# Regular expression in Bash shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have unix code which reads files from directory which matches predefined format and moves them to different directory for processing. Below is the existing working pattern and examples.

```
[A-Za-z]{5}.[A-Za-z]{2}.INPUT.[0-9]*(.TXT|.txt)$
```

**Old file Example1** :- STATS.WE.INPUT.20140227.TXT

**Old file Example1** :- STATS.WE.INPUT.20150245654.TXT

New file pattern has been changed and below is the sample file name and format I have tried.

**New file Example** :- STATS.WE.INPUT.20140227.A2345.465789765.TXT

**New file Example2**:- STATS.WE.INPUT.20140227.2345.465789765.TXT

**New file Example3**:- STATS.WE.INPUT.20140227.2345.46578976534234.TXT

```
[A-Za-z]{5}.[A-Za-z]{2}.INPUT.[0-9]*.[A-Za-Z0-9]*.[0-9]*(.TXT|.txt)$
```

Please let me know what need to be changed in above expression.

Comment: To make this more robust, start the regex with `^`, use `\.` to represent literal dots, and use `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer :

```
^[A-Za-z]{5}\.[A-Za-z]{2}\.INPUT.[0-9]*\.[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[0-9]+(.TX‌​T|.txt)$
```

Just from the all pattern I had this part : `\.[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[0-9]+` in order to match `.A2345.465789765` for example.

Comment: Thank you @kaldoran